# can two mysql users have the same name database

Tags: mysql, database

I want to import a db with the same name as an existing one.

If I use a different mysql user would there be any problem? *override*  perharps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can only have one MySQL database with any given name -- you will need to change the name of one (or both!) databases.

Comment: That's because they will be both available to the root user, so there is a conflict?

Comment: That's one way to think of it. A more accurate explanation would be that MySQL tracks everything about a database based on its name (for instance, all the data is in a folder named after the database), so there'd be no way for it to distinguish multiple DBs with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Two distinct databases must have two distinct names; MySQL cannot distinguish between them by name. A common practice on web hosting services for example, is to prefix the database names with the username, so the database would be called:

```
CREATE DATABASE user1_dbname
CREATE DATABASE user2_dbname
```

MySQL *can* separate permissions to tables in one database per user, which would make it possible for `user1` to have access only to a specific set of tables, and `user2` to have access to a different set, but that is confusing to manage.  Really, they should be separately named.

```
/* Separate SELECT permissions for user1 and user2 by table */
GRANT SELECT ON shared_dbname.user1table1,shared_dbname.user1table2 TO user1@localhost
GRANT SELECT ON shared_dbname.user2table1,shared_dbname.user2table2 TO user2@localhost
```